# 'base' no member of iterator in C++ anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to compile some code that was originally build in MS Visual Studio C++ 6.0 with Visual Studio 2013.

In the old code the following construct was often used for various data types (here for example for a string):

```
std::string someString;
someString = ....;
callSomeFunction(someString.begin().base());
```

So in order to enable the function to edit (in this example the string) the original buffer, the method `begin()` gets an iterator for it and the method `base()` returned a pointer to the first element of the buffer.

In the code this is not only used for strings, but for many many other datatypes as well.
Thus I was wondering, if there was a change to the standard library so the `base()` method is no longer supported?

Is there any replacement for it? Or do I have to change the code here? Since this was used very frequently, I would prefer to find a simpler solution to this.

Currently I get an error like:

> Error 3   error C2039: 'base' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_iterator>>'

Comment: My C++ is pretty much obsolete, but I don't recall normal `iterator`s having a `base()` function, just `reverse_iterator`s (and maybe others). Since you only want a pointer to the first element, why not just use `*(someString.begin())`?

Comment: @Jcl Correct, base is a member of [reverse_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

Comment: At least it can be found for [some iterator types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator).

Comment: There was a change to the Visual Studio library, but not to the standard. Your code was relying on non-portable features that were never part of the standard library in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

`base` was not standardized for container iterators. It exists for iterator adaptors such as `std::reverse_iterator` and `std::move_iterator`. Microsoft had to remove it from their implementation in order to comply with the ISO C++ standard.

To obtain a pointer from a container iterator, simply use `&* iter`. To get a pointer to the first element of the contiguous array backing a container, use `cont.data()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in:

```
callSomeFunction(&someString[0]);
```

That will be a `char*`. However, it would be safer and preferred if you could just change the signature of the function to take a `std::string&` - especially if there's any potential in that function just writing past the end of `someString`. I realize that's not always possible though.